# Get Predictions from Trained Pytorch Model

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, transfer-learning, torchvision

I am using transfer learning to fine tune an inception_v3 model. After I train the model and store the best version off I am attempting to use it to generate predictions for my test set. Below is an example of my attempt on one image.

```
img_test=Image.open("img.png")

#Perform same transformations to image that the model used
transform_pipeline = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
img_test = transform_pipeline(img_test)

# I believe this is adding in the batch size of 1, but in looking around online it looked like I needed it
img = img_test.unsqueeze(0)
img = Variable(img)

    
model_ft(img)
```

When I do the above I get

```
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

Which seems to imply my model weights are on my gpu and the variable is on the cpu, how do I move one or the other over so I can use it, or reference one that is on the opposite processor?

Comment: Use `.cpu()` or `.cuda()` function

Comment: move both to the same device of CPU or GPU. It is better to use convention as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/a/63922515/7129897 below throughout the program. This will ensure minimum errors

Answer (score 1):

As the error said, it seem that the input of the model (your img_test) is in the cpu.

Try to move the image to cuda before send it through your pre-trained model:

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available())
img_test = img_test.to(device)
```